# How to control exact position of Angular-UI Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've built a very basic Angular-UI popover within my application. However, the standard `popover-placement` options are not giving me what I need. I want my `popover-placement` to be `bottom`, as my HTML notes below. However, the element this popover is attached to is on the left edge of the screen, so half of it sppears off screen. Is there a way to explicitly set `left: 0px` for example so I can still place this popover on the bottom but avoid having it run off the screen? My other option is to just use `popover-placement='right'`, but this is less than ideal as it covers up other content.

```
<img ng-src="/images/{{player.status}}.png" alt="" id="status" popover='{{player.detail}}' popover-title='Player Status: {{player.detailedStatus}}' popover-trigger='mouseenter' popover-placement='bottom'>
```

Comment: Not really: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/432.  You can maybe adjust the positioning service.  There are a couple of other related popover placement issues that might be worth scanning to see if anyone else has a nice work around.

Answer (score 0):

Try with attributes without "popover" prefix.
As i see in directive source the prefix is not needed

```js
.directive( 'popoverPopup', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    scope: { title: '@', content: '@', placement: '@', animation: '&', isOpen: '&' },
    templateUrl: 'template/popover/popover.html'
  };
})
```

```html
<img ng-src="/images/{{player.status}}.png" alt="" id="status" popover='{{player.detail}}' title='Player Status: {{player.detailedStatus}}' popover-trigger='mouseenter' placement='bottom'>
```